# How to Connect kafka consumer topic using keytab in python

Tags: python, kafka-consumer-api, kerberos, keytab

I am new to Kafka and trying to read messages from kafka consumer topics using python. I am using below piece of code to read the messages.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

topic = 'topic'
bootstrap_servers = 'server'

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers = [bootstrap_servers],
               auto_offset_reset = 'earliest',
               enable_auto_commit = True,
               security_protocol = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
               sasl_mechanism = 'GSSAPI',
               consumer_timeout_ms = 1000)
```

When I run this, got the error message 'Could not find KfW installation' and failed to connect Kafka. Installed Kerberos for Windows MSI and reran, its able to establish the connectivity.

However, I am trying to avoid KfW installation in the local system, instead find a way to pass the keytab file and principal to use in the authentication process and read the data from kafka topic. (if its possible?)

But not sure, which argument of KafkaConsumer holds the keytab file.

Please suggest any better way available?

Comment: Check the Kafka documentation about the low-level Java security config file (typically `jaas*.conf`), how to set "client" and/or "broker" entries inside, and how to pass to it to the JAAS library thru a Java system property.